# iterate through all cells in collection view, visible or not

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that represents a weekly schedule for workers.
when I initialize the collection I make all the working slots as TRUE, meaning all the collection items should be filled as working.

I am now trying to implement a data model which is a boolean array that represents the weekly schedule, and will be passed to the collection view.
I cannot seem to find a way to iterate all the cells and update them. When I use visibleCells() I get an empty array.

some code:

```
    func updateShifts(schedule: WeeklySchedule, shift: Int){
    print(self.collectionView!.visibleCells.count) // prints 0

    for cell in self.collectionView!.visibleCells as! [SchedulePickupCell] {
        cell.setWorking(isWorkingInput: false)
    }

}
```

In the code, SchedulepickupCell is my custom collection view cell.
This code sits inside my class:

```
class ScheduleCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

Now I am not sure what being a visible cell means, regularly I get all items visible in my app, all i want is to iterate and to change their isHidden property to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `self.collectionView!.visibleCells.count` should contain all the visible cells, I believe you should approach it differently.

make sure that in `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` your setting your cells in according to the model and then:

1. Update your model
2. call `collectionView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

Just for sharing my solution, as Or Ron hinted me to:

I created an instance of my model in the collection view:

```
    var schedule = [[false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
                [false, false, false, false, false, false, false]]
```

Then I changed the func to update shifts:

```
    func updateShifts(schedule: WeeklySchedule){
    self.schedule = schedule
    self.collectionView!.reloadData()

}
```

Then in func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
function I always load with a reference to my schedule data